# Samba - Windows Network

Tags: windows, samba, security

I was recently checking my network and realized Samba was installed. When I go to "browse network" in the file explorer I see that there is "windows network" and my home folder is located inside. My question is that does Samba set this up by default or was it setup by a third-party? Just curious because I do not recall installing Samba or having any type of windows computer on my network.

Answer (score 0):

SMB client (samba) is installed by default (so you can connect to Windows shares), but SMB server is not.You have to install it if you want to create a Windows share.

Opening your own home folder in the file explorer is a special case: it display it as if it was a network share, but obviously, it is not.

HTH